# Rhizovision Image- Trying to find missing .dll files that prohibit my program from starting up

Tags: dllimport

I am trying to run my Rhizovision Imager software, but when I hit the app to execute, I am prompted with the errors that says I am  missing .dll files. I was wondering if anyone else has had this problem? For example, an error pops up that I am missing "***gcbase_md_vc120_v3_0_v5_0.dll***"

Answer (score 0):

I found this occurs if you have a different version of Pylon installed. Download and install the following "pylon_5_Runtime_5.0.12.11830". If you also wish to install the Pylon Viewer, download and install that first, then re-install the 5_Runtime above. Hope that helps!